# can't access classification_report metrics with list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, classification, list-comprehension

I am running experiments and evaluating results with `sklearn.metrics.classification_report`. If i pass a parameter `output_dict=True`, it returns a dictionary with all metrics per class (each class has its dictionary).

The problem is that i want a list of specific metrics (i.e. f1-score) of all classes. What i am trying to do is:

```py
report = classification_report(y_tr, y_pr, target_names=label_names, output_dict=True)
all_f1_scores = [metrics['f1-score'] for metrics in report.values()]
```

And this is the error traceback returned:

```py
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-1aa68c4b1f46> in <module>
----> 1 [metrics['f1-score'] for metrics in report.values()]

<ipython-input-103-0d9c92bd7736> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [metrics['f1-score'] for metrics in report.values()]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know what can be causing this error, but i am suspecting it has something to do with the `classification_report` function, since i was able to run this code with manually created nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last 3 items of the `classification_report` dictionary is not another dictionary, but the overall (float) metrics. You need to filter those out before using list comprehension.